# searching files containing '#' in file name extensions on windows 7

Tags: wildcard

Hi i have few files in my file system that have a '#' character in their name, e.g., .#3rdparty.properties.1.24.6   on Windows 7, when i tried a search '.#*.*'  it is treating the '#' as a wildcard '*',so it is returning me all files.

Does anyone know how to search files that have  a'#' in their file extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

i ran dir /s `*#*`  from DOS command prompt and got the required answer. But will be useful to know how to do this  from windows search

Answer (score 0):

[image]try System.FileName:~="#" that should do it, or even better System.FileExtension:~="#"

Comment: This did not bring back the right results. Try creating a text file in the format '.#3rdparty.properties.1.24.6'  and try searching for it